# How to force view creation with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, view

I have a view that MySQL refuses to create, because it references a column that doesn't exist:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'd.completed' in 'where clause'
```

Is there any way to force MySQL to create this view?  (Even though it will not be possible to use it until the column is created.)

(The reason I want to do this is I had a working view, which subsequently broken after a column was deleted.  I'm creating a schema migration to fix the view, but, as with all my other migrations, I would also like to be able to revert to the current situation.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and from the documentations, mysql doesn't support force views. It is a concept from Oracle. correct me if I am wrong with any official document link.

Answer (score -1):

You can force view creation from mysql command line with -f option:

```
mysql -f -u UserName -p < dump.sql
```